# Table columns not perfectly aligning right even when using format specifications in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to produce a table using python 3.6 and  using string formatting to align the columns to the right. However, I can't get it to properly align to the right no matter how high I adjust the width. Is there something I should be adding to the code?

Here's the code

```
x = "{0:>5} {1:>20} {2:>35}"
for i in range(1,11):
    print (x.format(i,i*(10**i),i*(10**(2*i))))
```

Here's the intended vs actual output [(image of output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA6A4.png)

Comment: That code works as intended - are you sure you're not looking at output from older attempts?

Comment: Tried it a couple of times and it still gives me the same pyramidic output as opposed to aligning each column perfectly to the right.

Comment: How are you viewing the output? The code's correct and does do what you're after... If you're viewing it by copy pasting into a word document or some IDE without a fixed width font etc... your results will differ...

Comment: I'm viewing it on python's stock IDLE - could that be the issue?

Comment: Seems likely... In options->configure IDLE - what font face is being used? If it's not a mono-spaced font - make it a mono spaced font... (if I change from  DejaVu Sans Mono to DejaVu Sans - I get something looking very similar to your screenshot)

Comment: You are right! The font face was the problem. Thanks